# setState in componentWillReceiveProps does not update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the state of the props componentWillReceiveProps - But it does not reflect the update in actual state variable when I check later for the values. As a result the values that are in UI and in state are not in sync.
I also tried to have a callback associated to the setState, which shows the correct value - but in actual app, the state is still not updated.

Code Snippet

```
 this.render = function () {
    var self = this;

     class SearchApp extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                value: [],
                action: "add"
            };
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
            self.searchInstance = this;
        }

        handleClick(e, value) {
            console.log(value);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Search
                    id="readonly_modifyStates"
                    readOnly={true}
                    value={readOnlyTokens}
                    logicMenu={['OR']}
                    action={this.state.action}
                />
            );
        }
};
this.addReadOnlyTokens = function (tokens) {
    // tokens = ['Managed Status = InSync, OutSync']
    readOnlyTokens = tokens;
   // 1 - Sending some value that needs to be updated in the existing 'value' variable
    this.searchInstance.setState({value: tokens, action:"add"});          
};
```

Search component code

```
class Search extends React.Component {
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {  
   switch(nextProps.action){
        case "add":
            //2 - The value will be updated on UI using lib addTokens method 
            this.searchWidget.addTokens(nextProps.value);
            break;
    }

    //3- At this moment I need to update the state 'value' so that both the UI and the actual state data is in sync - but not working
    this.setState({value: this.searchWidget.getAllTokens()}, function () {
            // Here, when value is checked - it shows the updated data - But when the control is in Search App code, the value falls back to ['Managed Status = InSync, OutSync'] 
            console.log('this.state ::: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state));
        });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="search-component"
             ref={el => this.el = el}>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

All I want to do is use the state to send the values from searchApp to the component (which updates the UI with massaged values) and then be able to sync those massaged value back to the state of the app - which now is pointing to the data that is used during setState call.

Reading through some articles, it seems that doing setState in componentWillReceiveProps() is OK to do - But I am not sure why the values are not getting in sync.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Is it possible for you create a plunker/jsbin/jsfiddle/codepen link?

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is considered unsafe. Have you tried using `getDerivedStateFromProps` ?